# SELECT From 2 Tables Depending On 2 Columns In First Table

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble getting this correct.

I have a table called 1_related

```
id,prod_pack,fk_prod_pack_id,fk_prod_pack_related,fk_prod_pack_related_id
'2', '0', '102', '0', '2482'
'3', '0', '102', '0', '3147'
'2294', '0', '102', '1', '10'
```

I have 2 other tables called 1_products and 1_packages

I want to join the contents of either table depending on the value of fk_prod_pack_related (0 for the 1_products table and 1 for the 1_packages table)

This query returns rows 2 and 3 from 1_related and joins the contents of 1_products

```
SELECT 
    r . *, p . *
FROM
    1_related AS r
        INNER JOIN
    1_products as p ON r.fk_prod_pack_related_id = p.id
        and r.fk_prod_pack_related = 0
WHERE
    r.prod_pack = 0
        and r.fk_prod_pack_id = 102
```

But I also need the data from 1_packages so I tried this but it return nothing

```
SELECT 
    r . *, p . *, s . *
FROM
    1_related AS r
        INNER JOIN
    1_products as p ON r.fk_prod_pack_related_id = p.id
        and r.fk_prod_pack_related = 0
        INNER JOIN
    1_packages as s ON r.fk_prod_pack_related_id = s.id
        and r.fk_prod_pack_related = 1
WHERE
    r.prod_pack = 0
        and r.fk_prod_pack_id = 102
```

Comment: Raphaël Althaus, I see you have edited the post. How do you get the formatting on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need left outer joins, since only one of the queries is going to match:

```
SELECT 
    r . *, p . *, s . *
FROM
    1_related AS r
        left outer JOIN
    1_products as p ON r.fk_prod_pack_related_id = p.id
        and r.fk_prod_pack_related = 0
        left outer JOIN
    1_packages as s ON r.fk_prod_pack_related_id = s.id
        and r.fk_prod_pack_related = 1
WHERE
    r.prod_pack = 0
        and r.fk_prod_pack_id = 102
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon For Your Help